# Why can infinite product only be zero if one of the factors is zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

I was reading about the Riemann zeta function in the region $Re(Z) > 1$, where
it can be represented by the Euler product formula. And the book mentioned that
there can be no zeros in this region, since each factor  $1/(1 - 1/p^s)$ is never zero.

Can someone explain why the product can't converge to zero? For example, 
consider the infinite product $1/2 \cdot 1/3 \cdot 1/4 \cdots$.  This seems to converge to zero,
but each factor is not zero.

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: when dealing with infinite products, we usually say the product *diverges* when the limit of partial products is 0. This directly corresponds to similar usage for sums and limits whose values are $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This argument itself seems indeed wrong, as your counterexample shows.

However, the members in your counterexample tend to $0$, but the members of the Euler product formula tend to $1$ *from above* (as $p\to\infty$).

'*Taking logarithm*', the product will become a sum, and in this sum each summand is positive. Probably that was the intended meaning..

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerProduct.html) they explain your question.

In particular they show

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_k}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}>1$$

Answer (score 0):

For all prime $p$ we have that

$$\frac{1}{1-1/p^s} = \frac{1}{\frac{p^s-1}{p^s}} = \frac{p^s}{p^s-1}>1$$

In that case the terms are not going to $0$.